# Why does the Google Maps app need my phone call permission?

Tags: permissions, google-maps

Is there any way this is justified?
Seems like Google is becoming an evil spy to me, cause this is not the first time their apps need ridiculous permissions.

[image]

Comment: Related: [New access permissions for google maps 9.1.1](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89806/new-access-permissions-for-google-maps-9-1-1) (no legitimate answer yet)

Comment: Write to Google. See if they can help you. Because I found nothing on Internet.

Comment: @MANI How can I reach them?

Answer (score 1):

If you receive a call, an app may wish to know this. It could then free some of the phone's resources (CPU/RAM) to allow the call to be answered quickly, along with lowering or muting the navigation voice, etc. Those permissions may also be related to allowing the app to call a particular location, or even put there for a feature not compatible with your phone or fully released yet.

Individual permissions encompass access to many different things, so not every permission is explicitly used for malicious purposes. *That of course doesn't mean you shouldn't be cautious.*

If you really don't trust an app, use a permission manager. Your phone may have one already built in, with [no root required for pre android 4.4.2 devices](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/08/app-ops-androids-hidden-permission.html). Or just download one from the app store. They will allow to you disable individual permissions for specific apps. For example, most games have no business with your GPS, so disabling it won't hurt anything. Be careful, because as I stated before, some permissions are beneficial for particular purposes.

Comment: Looks like a grate app, but crashes the moment I open it. :-\

Comment: What version of Android are you running? There are alternatives on the market and others off the market as well.

Comment: Android 4.4.2 on a Galaxy S5

Comment: Yes it appears that 4.4.2 has the built-in permission manager removed. "APK Permission Remover" may be what you are looking for, however I haven't tried it myself. If you try it, let me know if it works.

Comment: Permissions manager doesn't seem to be able to remove permissions from built-in apps.